# Formik - Render Checkbox group outside Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, checkboxlist, formik, dynamicform

I'm trying to render a checkbox group dynamically outside the `<Fromik>` component.
Everything is working fine and I'm able to fill the checkbox array with the checked values.
The problem is that when I uncheck one of the checkboxes, the array set its value to "false" and not remove it from the array.
How can I remove the entry from the array and not set its value to "false"?

Here's an example ...

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-dynamic-inputs-with-formik-xr9qg

Comment: The demo you posted works fine for me, how are you seeing false?

Comment: @Auticcat Yes I fixed it and figured out what was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to post your solution then, so if someone has the same problem he can use this question as future reference! glad you got it done